# Android - notification does not appear in status bar

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, intentservice

When starting an `IntentService` to upload a file in the background, I want to show a notification to the user that the upload is in progress by calling `showNotification()` from inside my service:

```
private void showNotification() {

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cloud_upload_black_24dp)  
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) 
            .setContentTitle("Uploading")
            .setContentText("Your upload is in progress.")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Now here's my problem: the notification appears on the lock screen, **but not in the status bar when the screen is unlocked**. What am I missing?

Deployment target is API level 24, so a missing `NotificationChannel` should not be the cause.

Comment: notification channel is added in api level >26 ,for oreo and higher versions , means your code is working to show notification in lock screen, are you testing on oreo device ?

Comment: i have added answer , please try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so dumb. Turns out the notification was displayed all the time, but with a black icon on black background.

Changed the icon colour in the xml from

`android:fillColor="#FF000000"`
to 
`android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"`

and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getmContext(), 0, new Intent(getmContext(), MainActivity.class), 0);
    android.app.Notification pp = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getmContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentText(getMessage())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getmContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, pp);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code which is working fine with target `SDK` **25**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)

                .setStyle(inboxStyle)

                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

where `NOTIFICATION_ID`

```
 public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
```

Comment: Thanks, starting from this I could find the mistake step after step

Comment: Do you mean using the answer ?